# What does "matscale" function in Matlab actually do?

Tags: python, matlab, transfer-function

I'm trying to implement a convertor from z to s time for transfer function in Python. 
Matlab give us an opportunity to do this using d2c function. But i can't get what the "matscale" function does.

I've stucked in mscale.m file with calling matscale(abs(a),0.01) function. There is no description and no such function in matlab website at all. I can't open it, because its extention is .mex32 (i guess). All that i found in internet is that it may implement the "scale the matrix using the projection radius", but i'm not sure it's correct (http://www.adras.com/Purpose-of-matscale-in-Control-Toolbox.t124458-80.html)
 Could you please explain me what this function does or share a source code? i use matlab 2018a

[~,s] = matscale(abs(a),0.01);

Comment: This is not a built-in function. If there is no source code and no documentation you will have to ask the creator of the function.

Comment: i understood it, i guess it's a common function, m.b. some kind of matrix transformation of some one

Answer (score 0):

If someone needs the solution of my problem, i found that the "matscale" function executes the same thing as function "balance". Python libs contain this function